# Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to access variables passed from the server to the client with ejs

My server file:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('chat', {user: req.user, message: null});
});
```

My client file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" const="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <title>Simple Chat App</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1>Super Chat</h1>
</header>

<section>
    <div id="change_username">
        <input id="username" type="text"/>
        <button id="send_username" type="button">Change username</button>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="chatroom">
    <section id="feedback"></section>
</section>


<section id="input_zone">
    <input id="message" class="vertical-align" type="text"/>
    <button id="send_message" class="vertical-align" type="button">Send</button>
</section>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <% var user = <% user %> %>
    console.log(user);
</script>
<script src="chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error:

```
Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: replace `<% var user = <% user %> %>` with `var user = <%  user %>`

Comment: @PHPNinja — That will fix the error, but still not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <% var user = <% user %> %>
> ```

You can't nest `<% %>` blocks. You are either inside EJS mode or outside it. You can't go into Extra Deep EJS Mode.

---

Aside, you also can't just output a variable into client-side JS. You need to generate JavaScript source code from the variable. `JSON.stringify` is a good way to generate object, array and string literals from objects, arrays and strings.

```
<script>
    const user = <%- JSON.stringify(user); %>
    console.log(user);
</script>
```

Note that use of `<%-` to output without escaping for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If VS Code does not understand you need to install "ejs language support" in VS Code from the extension section. I had faced the same problem and that is how I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

it says that it cannot find closing tag for your ejs template.
you don't need the surrounding ejs template notation in script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var user = '<%= user %>'
console.log(user);
</script>
```

Try this.
GOOD LUCK. :)

Comment: `<%=` performs HTML escaping, not JS escaping.

Comment: It gives the wrong output if (a) `user` is not a string or (b) `user` is a string containing a `&` or `<` and it breaks the script if it is a string which contains a `'`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here, you just have to replace the value of the user in the template.

```
 var user = "<%=user%>" // Please change this line
```

**Updated Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" const="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <title>Simple Chat App</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1>Super Chat</h1>
</header>

<section>
    <div id="change_username">
        <input id="username" type="text"/>
        <button id="send_username" type="button">Change username</button>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="chatroom">
    <section id="feedback"></section>
</section>


<section id="input_zone">
    <input id="message" class="vertical-align" type="text"/>
    <button id="send_message" class="vertical-align" type="button">Send</button>
</section>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var user = "<%= user %>" // problem is here 
    console.log(user);
</script>
<script src="chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I Hope this helps you.

Comment: var user = <% user %> wont work. <% is for control flow. to Output a certain thing you have to use <%= user %> . equal sign after the percentage sign is necessary.

Comment: @WaleedShafiq — That does escaping for HTML. It isn't being output into HTML.